# calling a function after forEach has been completed in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a method which needs to be called only after my forEach block completes executing. Right now in my code the function gets called first after that my forEach block gets executed. Here is the piece of code,

```
function processData(data) {
      angular.forEach(data.ITINERARY.LIST_BOUNDS, function(bound, boundIndex) {
            angular.forEach(bound.LIST_SEGMENT, function(segment, index) {
                $q.all([
                        ServiceLocationAssistant.getAirport(segment.ORIGIN.LOCATION_CODE),
                        ServiceLocationAssistant.getAirport(segment.DESTINATION.LOCATION_CODE)
                    ])
                    .then(function(locations) {
                        segment.ORIGIN.location = locations[0];
                        segment.DESTINATION.location = locations[1];
                    });
            });
          });
         $scope.flightSection(processedData);//This method needs to be called
    }
```

Comment: No, the foreach will pretty certainly execute before the `flightSection` call after it. More likely the Promise finishes later, no?! We'd need to know a lot more about what your asynchronous code needs to do to suggest a good solution here.

Comment: I have to set the JSON with some value which i am doing in foeEach block, and after that i have to do some operation on the changed JSON in the Flight Section.